# R Subset matching contiguous blocks

Tags: r

I have a dataframe.

```
dat <- data.frame(k=c("A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A"),
a=c(4,2,4,7,5,8,3,2),b=c(2,5,3,5,8,4,5,8),
stringsAsFactors = F)

  k a b
1 A 4 2
2 A 2 5
3 B 4 3
4 B 7 5
5 B 5 8
6 A 8 4
7 A 3 5
8 A 2 8
```

I would like to subset contiguous blocks based on variable k. This would be a standard approach.

```
#using rle rather than levels
kval <- rle(dat$k)$values
for(i in 1:length(kval))
{
  subdf <- subset(dat,dat$k==kval[i])
  print(subdf)
  #do something with subdf
}

  k a b
1 A 4 2
2 A 2 5
6 A 8 4
7 A 3 5
8 A 2 8

  k a b
3 B 4 3
4 B 7 5
5 B 5 8

  k a b
1 A 4 2
2 A 2 5
6 A 8 4
7 A 3 5
8 A 2 8
```

So the subsetting above obviously does not work the way I intended. Any elegant way to get these results?

```
k a b
1 A 4 2
2 A 2 5

k a b
1 B 4 3
2 B 7 5
3 B 5 8

k a b
1 A 8 4
2 A 3 5
3 A 2 8
```

Comment: Ah of course! lengths. _facepalm_ thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create a grouping variable

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(dat)[, grp := rleid(k)]
dat
#    k a b grp
#1: A 4 2   1
#2: A 2 5   1
#3: B 4 3   2
#4: B 7 5   2  
#5: B 5 8   2
#6: A 8 4   3
#7: A 3 5   3
#8: A 2 8   3
```

We can group by 'grp' and do all the operations within the 'grp' using standard data.table methods.

---

Here is a `base R` option to create 'grp'

```
dat$grp <-  with(dat, cumsum(c(TRUE, k[-1]!= k[-length(k)])))
```